# Installing NVIDIA Visual Profiler (NVVP) on Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur, java

I am trying to install NVIDIA Visual Profiler (NVVP) on my macbook with Big Sur v11.2.1.
I downloaded NVVP from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/assets/DevToolsCTKMacHosts/ctk11_3_0/nvidia-visual-profiler-mac) and OpenJDK from [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot).

I am getting the following error:

```
bash-3.2$ ./nvvp -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller (file:/Applications/nvvp/libnvvp/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

If I just run `./nvvp` without `-vm` parameter, the workspace selection window pops up but it is not clickable at all.

Before the above-mentioned solutions, I tried to install `cuda_10.2.89_mac.dmg`, which contains NVVP. However, I realized that it is not fully installed because there is no `/Developer` folder on my system and CUDA installer tried to use `/Developer` folder:

```
bash-3.2$ ls -l /usr/local/cuda/
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    58 Oct 30  2019 CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.txt -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.txt
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    36 Oct 30  2019 EULA.txt -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/EULA.txt
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    53 Oct 30  2019 NsightSystems-2019.5.2.16 -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/NsightSystems-2019.5.2.16
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    31 Oct 30  2019 bin -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/bin
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    31 Oct 30  2019 doc -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/doc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    34 Oct 30  2019 extras -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/extras
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    35 Oct 30  2019 include -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/include
drwxr-xr-x  81 root  wheel  2592 May  2 00:04 lib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    37 Oct 30  2019 libnsight -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/libnsight
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    35 Oct 30  2019 libnvvp -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/libnvvp
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    51 Oct 30  2019 nsight-compute-2019.5.0 -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/nsight-compute-2019.5.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    44 Oct 30  2019 nsightee_plugins -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/nsightee_plugins
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    32 Oct 30  2019 nvvm -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/nvvm
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    33 Oct 30  2019 nvvmx -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/nvvmx
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    35 Oct 30  2019 samples -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/samples
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    31 Oct 30  2019 src -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/src
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    33 Oct 30  2019 tools -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/tools
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    39 Oct 30  2019 version.txt -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-10.2/version.txt
```

Do I need to make a /Developer folder or install something else here?

Comment: The `org.eclipse.osgi` version mentioned in the "illegal reflective access" message is from  a very old version of Eclipse. It is not going to work with anything later than Java 8.

Comment: @greg-449 You are right, I tried with Java 8 and the "illegal reflective access" message disappeared. However the workspace selection window is still non-clickable.

Comment: I don't know anything about this particular tool but it looks like it is based on an old Eclipse. Older versions of Eclipse have problems on Big-Sur. The problems are fixed in the current version of Eclipse but using that would require the tool to be updated by Nvidia.